# Why isn't my member information transferring from the razor page to the Controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

My razor view is only sending the two textboxes fields. I need it to either send a field called "isDesigner" which is a bool or I need to be able to retrieve this information in from the database in the controller based on what the "Email" is.

Here is the cshtml

```
@model Member
@{ ViewData["Title"] = "Index"; }

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form method="post">
            <div>
                <h4>Login</h4>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Email: </label>
                    <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control" /><span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Password: </label>
                    <input asp-for="Password" class="form-control" /><span asp-validation-for="Password" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<label> <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Members" asp-action="Register">Register</a></label>
<label> <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="admin" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Admin</a></label>
```

This is the controller side

```
public class MembersController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ThreeDeePrintingHubContext _context;
        private readonly ILogger<MembersController> _logger;

        public MembersController(ThreeDeePrintingHubContext threeDeeHubContext, ILogger<MembersController> logger)
        {
            _context = threeDeeHubContext;
            _logger = logger;
        }
       
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(Member member)
        {
            var isValidMember = _context.Members.Where(x => x.Email == member.Email && x.Password == member.Password).Any();

            if (isValidMember)
            {
                return Redirect("/Product");
            }
            else
            {

                TempData["Message"] = "Invalid user";
                return View();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, if you want to send the bool value from the view to the controller, you should firstly get it or set it in the view and then send it to the controller.

More details, you could refer to below codes:

```
<form method="post">
    <div>
        <h4>Login</h4>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Email: </label>
            <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control" /><span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Password: </label>
            <input asp-for="Password" class="form-control" /><span asp-validation-for="Password" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">isDesigner: </label>
            <input asp-for="isDesigner" class="form-control" /><span asp-validation-for="isDesigner" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Member class:

```
public class Member
{
    public string Email { get; set; }


    public string Password { get; set; }


    public bool isDesigner { get; set; }
}
```

Result:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
   [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(Member member)
        {
```

This was the answer

> ```
>         var myMember = _context.Members.Where(x => x.Email == member.Email && x.Password == member.Password).FirstOrDefault();
>         var isValidMember = myMember != null;
> ```

```
        if (isValidMember)
        {
            if (myMember.IsDesigner)
            {
                return Redirect("/Product/DesignerIndex");
            }
            else
            {
                return Redirect("/Product");
            }
        }
        else
        {

            TempData["Message"] = "Invalid user";
            return View();
        }
    }
        // GET: MembersController/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(int id)
    {
        return View();
    }
```